# VBA Someone else is working in "NETWORK_DRIVE_EXCELFILE.xlsm" right now. Please try again later

Tags: excel, vba, save, network-driver

I have an Excel macro running all day, and saves the macro workbook and content to a network drive, every 10 minutes. Other users should only be able to open the workbook as read only, but once in a while the workbook fails to save. When this happens, there is an Excel message stating, "Someone else is working in "NETWORK_DRIVE_EXCELFILE.xlsm" right now. Please try again later." How is this possible, and is there a way for the macro to detect, when this occurs? If there is, I could write an error handle for it.